# How to access `java.home` being used by Gradle?

Tags: gradle

`./gradlew properties` shows no properties having the value of `${JAVA_HOME}` and the following emit an error indicating no such property exists:

```
println org.gradle.java.home
println gradle.java.home
println java.home
```

In the end, I want to specify a compile-time dependency on the `tools.jar` that's part of the JDK. For example:

```
dependencies {
  compile files("${java.home}/lib/tools.jar")
}
```

Answer (score 7):

`println System.properties['java.home']`

Answer (score 5):

It's not very well documented from what I can find, but you can use the Jvm object in Gradle like this:

```
println org.gradle.internal.jvm.Jvm.current().getJavaHome()
```

There's a [discussion thread](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/getting-java-version-of-current-gradle-run/6506) here that shows a couple other usages.

Plus, if you just want to address the tools jar, you can use

```
org.gradle.internal.jvm.Jvm.current().toolsJar
```

Comment: Internal APIs may be removed from the public interface, so it's risky to rely on them.

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to set the JAVA_HOME used by Gradle you can setting the environment property:

> org.gradle.java.home
>
> Specifies the Java home for the Gradle build process. The value can be set to either a jdk or jre location, however, depending on what your build does, jdk is safer. A reasonable default is used if the setting is unspecified.

If you are trying to reference the existing JAVA_HOME being used, you can gain access to the System Environment properties in this way:

```
java.home = "$System.env.JAVA_HOME"
```

Comment: That documentation says a reasonable default is used if the setting is unspecified. I'm trying to access the property itself. I would expect the `println` lines to work but they're not.

Comment: Try adding a println for `"$System.env.JAVA_HOME"` and see what you get.

Comment: I understand I can set it myself. Is there a documentation bug when it says there's a reasonable default?

Comment: `println "Java home: $System.env.JAVA_HOME"` prints `Java home: null` in the default closure of `build.gradle`

Answer (score 0):

The easiest ways I know using Groovy are these:

```
def java.home = "$System.env.JAVA_HOME"
```

or

```
def java.home = "echo $JAVA_HOME".execute().text.trim()
```