# Gradle get the Java classpath inside build.gradle

Tags: gradle, classpath

FindBugs outputs errors such as "The missing classes are missing..." so I checked it's classpath by writing this in my `build.gradle`:

```
findbugsMain {
    classpath.each {
        println it
    }
}
```

It doesn't print anything, which means that the classpath is empty. From various questions on SO, I gathered that it needs to contain the classpath to the Java classes (every class written as missing is a native class).

I don't want to hardcode this because this project should work on multiple computers. The classpath of the native java classes should be found from Gradle itself (it must have it somewhere! But I can't find where).

I tried adding the classpath myself, by using:

```
findbugsMain {
    classpath += sourceSets.main.output
    classpath += sourceSets.main.compileClasspath
    classpath += sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
    classpath += sourceSets.test.output
    classpath += sourceSets.test.compileClasspath
    classpath.each {
        println it
    }
}
```

but this prints:

```
/.../build/classes/java/main
/.../build/resources/main
/.../build/classes/java/test
/.../build/resources/test
/.../.gradle/caches/.../junit-4.12.jar
/.../.gradle/caches/.../hamcrest-core-1.3.jar
```

This still doesn't include the Java JARS...

Here is an example of the missing classes:

```
> Task :findbugsMain 
The following classes needed for analysis were missing:
  java.lang.Object
  java.io.PrintStream
  java.lang.NoSuchFieldError
  java.lang.System

> Task :findbugsTest 
The following classes needed for analysis were missing:
  java.lang.Object
  java.lang.NoSuchFieldError
```

I know I'm very close to finding the solution, but at this point I do not see what the correct line is...

---

Edit after the comments: trying to use JAVA_HOME. According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36273810/how-to-access-java-home-being-used-by-gradle):

```
println org.gradle.internal.jvm.Jvm.current().getJavaHome()
```

prints `/usr/lib/jvm/java-10-openjdk-amd64`. However, what I'm expecting is the Java 8 home, because this gives the JVM used to run Gradle, not the one used to compile the project (specified by `sourceCompatibily = '1.8'` in my `build.gradle` file).

Comment: I'm using Debian and installed multiple JDKs through apt-get, so I expect the classpath to be hardcode-able to `/usr/local/bin` or a similar path, but the aim is to have something working for any JDK (according to the sourceCompatibility Gradle field) on any computer...

Comment: Isn't this what `JAVA_HOME` is for?

Comment: No @lu.koerfer, it gives the Java home used to run Gradle (1.10 on my machine) but the JDK used for the project itself should be 1.8 (as set with `sourceCompatibility = 1.8`). There must be a way to access it though: I checked and Gradle does use the 1.8 JDK to build the project... there MUST be a way to access it.

Comment: I thought that `sourceCompatibility` only causes the compiler to run in another mode. See the command line option [`-source`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/tools/javac.html#GUID-AEEC9F07-CB49-4E96-8BC7-BCC2C7F725C9) of *javac*. Did you actually verify that Gradle is using another JDK, not just another version of Java?